# Blocked By Play Protect occurs again after updating apk with the same signature

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, game-engine, google-play-protect

I made a game with unity 2d, a simple 2d game with no need to any permission on android, the "Blocked by play protect" was occurred at first release, I submitted an appeal to play protect support for removing this issue, it removed, but only for the apk file that I submitted in my appeal, any new build with the same signature of the same project will show the warning again in devices.

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are trying to make an Internet connection via HTTP or expired HTTPS license. This is one of the reasons this warning appears.

Comment: I checked again, and I found out there is a link to my website in the app, it opens up my website, could it be the reason for the problem?

Comment: Is it http or https?

Comment: It is http. Please change it to: https://ssdt.ir. If You have any similar link you have to edit that too. See if it works.

Comment: that unintentionally turned into a link. You have to change it to: h-t-t-p-s-://-ssdt-.-ir